# How do you block a specific process (such as vim) from accessing a mounted disk?

Tags: permissions, mount, io, audit

If I have a disk mounted on my hard-drive, I want to be able to block all but specific processes from having read/write access to that disk. Currently, I'm thinking the best way is to audit the disk and kill the processes when seen accessing files in the disk, but are there any methods to stop those processes before they actually access them?

Edit 1:

Let me elaborate with an example. For example, I might want to block all processes from reading from and writing to a mounted disk *except* vim. So, if an unauthorized user calls `touch /mnt/mounteddisk/foo` then I would block that.

I would also assume that there's a big difference between having access to a disk and having access to files inside the disk. For example, the former would block calling `ls` on the mounted disk directory, and the latter wouldn't. But the latter could block `vim` trying to read a file inside the disk. I am currently looking for the former.

Comment: more easy way to run processes with user who doesn't have any permission on mounted partition.

Comment: The answer depends on the actual problem you need to solve. Do you want to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the files? Prevent the file indexer from reading the disk?

Comment: To prevent unauthorized users i believe. But i dont know what a file indexer is

Comment: But im not just trying to prevent users. Even if the user has read/write privileges i want to allow only specific actions. For example i might only want to allow the "vi" process to be able to read or write files

Comment: What OS will you be using?

Comment: CentOS 6 atm. Will hopefully want on Debian systems later too

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you care what tool is used to access the disk?  If the user has read permissions, that user can read the data disk. If the user has write permissions, that user can modify the data on the disk.  Any method you put into place to try to identify the tool being used will likely be incomplete and unreliable. For example, your audit method can't prevent `cat /dev/null > /some/file` from truncating a file because the user's shell will truncate the file before your audit method kills it.

Comment: This can probably be done using selinux or apparmor. But note that vim is almost a Turing Machine, so allowing it but disallowing touch won't really be a limitation. `function touch() { vim -c wq $1; }`